# setting proxy options in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to setup proxy in selenium for chrome driver.
I have seen many answers on this, tried most of them. None worked for me.

Selenium version 2.53.2

```
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % proxy)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "/Users/MacX/Downloads/chromedriver")
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
browser.get(url)
```

where proxy is

```
PROXY1 = "111.98.9.54:8080"

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': PROXY1,
    'ftpProxy': PROXY1,
    'sslProxy': PROXY1,
    'noProxy': None
    })
```

I am getting this error

```
  capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'setCapability'
```

Comment: Then what should i use to set driver path??

Comment: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Comment: I have used same thing which is writtten in the documentation 
`capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
`

Comment: Am I missing any import statement in python?

Comment: pls help me, someone